# How to host React app on CloudFront but make it Private to the Organization

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting

I am trying to host a React App for the organization and we have the security thing that does not let us host directly from S3, So Trying to host it using CloudFront but Found that CloudFront is public and the content we are trying to publish must be within the organization. Is anyone familiar with ways to host Web App in CloudFront but make it private with in the organization

Answer (score 0):

You can't host web app on CloudFront, CloudFront is CDN that you can set up to point to a specific endpoint that is hosting your app. Second thing is that main purpose of CloudFront is to make your content available to users across globe with low latency by content caching, not to use it internally within your organization.

I am not sure how you security policies look like but I would argue that S3 is pretty secure if you know how to set it up correctly, e.g. correct bucket policies and KMS encryption.

But if you really can't host your app on S3, then you will need to set up your own web server. For example, you could spin up EC2 instance to serve as your web server and place it into private VPC to achieve complete isolation from the outside world.